# Jenkins execute all sub jobs before marking a top job fail or pass?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
def jobs = [
    'subjob1': true,
    'subjob2': false,
    'subjob3': true
]

pipeline
{
    agent { label "ag1" }

    stages
    {
        stage('stage1')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    jobs.each
                    {
                        if ("$it.value".toBoolean())
                        {
                            stage("Stage $it.key")
                            {
                                build([job:"$it.key", wait:true, propagate:true])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This Jenkins job triggers other sub-jobs (via [pipeline build step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)): `subjob1`, `subjob2`, `subjob3`. If any of the sub-jobs fail, this job immediately fails (`propagate:true`).

However, what I'd like to do is continue executing all jobs. And mark this one as failed if one or more sub-jobs fail. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. You can simply use a [catchError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) block for this.

```
def jobs = [
    'subjob1': true,
    'subjob2': false,
    'subjob3': true
]

pipeline
{
    agent any

    stages
    {
        stage('stage1')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    jobs.each
                    {
                        if ("$it.value".toBoolean())
                        {
                            stage("Stage $it.key")
                            {
                               catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') 
                                {
                                    echo "Building"
                                    build([job:"$it.key", wait:true, propagate:true])
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `def jobFailed = false` for?

Comment: @Danijel please ignore that.  Was going to propose something different by setting a flag. But this solution is simpler.

Comment: OK, than please delete the line.

Comment: Hi @ycr. In the solution provided, we have to wait for all the jobs to be executed one by one. It's not effective. It's overkill in comparison to executing them independently in parallel.

Comment: @MarcinKłopotek I don't disagree. But that's not what OP asked for. There can be reasons for executing in sequence although parallel may seem efficient.

Comment: Good enough for my use case, simple and clean solution. Tried it and it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing all the jobs one by one, you can execute them in [`parallel`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel). This way, all the jobs will be executed independently of each other and `stage1` will fail only if one or more jobs fails.

According to [the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel)

> The `parallel` directive takes a map from branch names to closures and an optional argument `failFast` which will terminate all branches upon a failure in any other branch.

So, we have to transform the `jobs` to [a `Map`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html) of stage names to [Closures](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) that will execute in parallel. We will use [`jobs.collectEntries()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) to build the mapping and pass it as the argument to the `parallel` directive:

```
stage('Parallel') {
    steps {
        script {
            parallel(jobs.collectEntries {
                [(it.key): {
                    if (it.value) {
                        build(job: it.key)
                    } else {
                        echo "Skipping job execution: ${it.key}"
                        // This is required to mark the parallel stage as skipped - it is not required for the solution to work
                        org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(it.key)
                    }
                }]
            })
        }
    }
}
```

We can omit the `wait` and `propagate` flags in the [`build` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) because they are set by default.

In the provided solution the `Parallel` stage (and the resulting build) will fail only if one or more `jobs` fails. Additionally, if you have [Blue Ocean](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/) plugin installed you will see a nice view graph of `Parallel` stage along with all the parallel children:

[image]